# What's the equivalent of this Flex MX code in Spark?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mx, flex-spark

What's the equivalent of an inline itemRenderer checkbox element in spark?

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Eliminar" dataField="eliminar"  width="100" textAlign="center">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center">
                            <mx:CheckBox id="chkEliminar" change="{data.eliminar = chkEliminar.selected}" selected="{data.eliminar}"/>
                            </mx:HBox>
                        </fx:Component>                     
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                        </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline itemRenderers work the same in spark as they did in Halo.

Spark has its own CheckBox component `<s:CheckBox>` you *could* use, but you can also continue to use the Halo CheckBox `<mx:CheckBox>` you've got in your example.

Comment: The thing is, if I use the spark checkbox the "data" property I use there is no longer valid.

Comment: @overmann, This is true. I would just stick with the Halo CheckBox if you have to use inline itemRenderers. Otherwise, look into creating an actual `ItemRenderer` component. Check out http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html for more info.

Comment: +! for the first line of your answer.  "Inline itemRenderers work the same in spark as they did in Halo."  See my answer for a bit more about this if you wanted to use Spark components as renderers to MX Components.

Comment: @Flextras, I added more info in my reply to overmann`s comment as well. +1 to your answer for providing an actual example. :)

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Jason's answer

```
Inline itemRenderers work the same in spark as they did in Halo
```

I will add that if you want to use Spark Components in a renderer, then you either need to implement IDataRenderer interface or use the itemRenderer class.  [More info here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html).  I would rewrite your existing itemRenderer like this to be Spark:

```
<fx:Component>
<s:ItemRenderer>
 <s:CheckBox id="chkEliminar" change="{data.eliminar = chkEliminar.selected}" selected="{data.eliminar}"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
</fx:Component>
```

For the moment, I'm ignoring the act that binding in an itemRenderer is consdered a bad practice and you really should use the dataChange event to modify the selected values.

Comment: @Flextras, Out of curiosity, why is binding in an itemRenderer considered bad practice? Not criticizing, just curious.

Comment: @Jason Towne It is known to be a drag on performance.  Binding is an expensive operation.  I assume it relates to the way binding works and how the MXML is translated into ActionScript.  With the Flextras AutoComplete, for example, I have fixed most "memory leak" complaints by re-writing client's itemRenderers to not use binding.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the other answers here are good for this case, where there's only one subitem, but if you want the itemrenderer to have a layout like an HBox you need to specify it manually:

```
<s:itemRenderer>
  <fx:Component>
    <s:itemRenderer>
       <s:layout>
         <s:HorizontalLayout horizontalAlign="center"/>
       </s:layout>
       <mx:CheckBox id="chkEliminar" change="{data.eliminar = chkEliminar.selected}" selected="{data.eliminar}"/>
     </s:itemRenderer>
   </fx:Component>                     
 </s:itemRenderer>
```

Comment: Why use an HBox if he just has one child component?  It's overkill.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Because if he starts adding to the code this will behave the same as the halo components. Without the layout, the renderer means something different from an HBox.